# find if the array element is null or not in 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, null

I was writing this particular program and I get an error as follows:-

> The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to
>   int.

The error is in this line :- `if (a[i][j] != null)`
I want to check if the array element is `null`

```
    Integer [][] arr = new Integer [6][6];
    int a,b;
    a=0;b=0;
    for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
    {          
        for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if (a[i][j] != null)
            {
                a=a+a[i][j];
            }

            if(b<a)
        {
            b=a;
        }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have written `a[i][j]`, or made a mistake while writing the question

Comment: Look at the top few lines in your code. What is the type of `a`? Can it be indexed? By the way, this is what happens when you use meaningless variable names like `a`, `b`, etc.

Comment: `a[i][j]` or `arr[i][j]` ?

Comment: You have mistake in code. arr[i][j] instead of a[i][j]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c - Checking for null in a 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39823004/c-checking-for-null-in-a-2d-array)

Comment: @haider_kazal it's a typo in the code, not a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you defined `a` as an **int** variable  `int a,b;` and you used it as **array** `a[i][j]`.  
So make sure that you change `if (a[i][j] != null)` to `if (arr[i][j] != null)` 
and also change `a=a+a[i][j];` to `a=a+arr[i][j];` or `a+=arr[i][j];`